# More Information about Application.Caller with VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have been using Application.Caller in a comparison in my code. When a user clicks a commandbutton, I am assuming Application.Caller returns the name of the command button, but am unsure.

I am trying to do something like: msgbox(Application.Caller), but realized its not the right data type. How would I go figuring out what Application.Caller actually is?

Comment: HTH http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193687.aspx

Comment: Hm...not quite sure I understand it completely. The comparison I'm doing is this: `If StrComp(Application.Caller, NodeSpanDict.Keys(i), 1) = 0` . Before it seemed to work...but now its not working when I try and get application.caller in a msgbox

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As shown in that [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff193687.aspx), `Application.Caller` will not always be of `String` type

You are using `StrComp` which compares 2 strings. I would recommend using this.

```
Sub Sample()
    If TypeName(Application.Caller) = "String" Then
        MsgBox StrComp(Application.Caller, "Button1")
    End If
End Sub
```

And assign this macro to the Form Button which you have on the worksheet.

If you see the example given in the link that I gave earlier, it automatically will be clear to you :)

```
Select Case TypeName(Application.Caller)
    Case "Range"
        v = Application.Caller.Address
    Case "String"
        v = Application.Caller
    Case "Error"
        v = "Error"
    Case Else
        v = "unknown"
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. I actually decided against using Application.Caller in favor of another variable I have which has the string of the form button clicked. I'll keep this in mind for the future though. Thanks for the clarification!