# Add shape to range (.AddShape method)

Tags: excel, vba

For Excel-2007:

Without using select, what is the best way to add a shape to a specific range or cell?

So far the best way I've found is by calculating using `EntireColumn.Left` and the like.

Can the `AddShape` method be used within a range to automatically create a shape within the range? Or must `AddShape` always locate a new shape relative to the upper-left corner of the document?

Comment: Maybe this could help [vba to add a shape at a specific cell location in Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038893/vba-to-add-a-shape-at-a-specific-cell-location-in-excel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example of placing a Shape (in this case a TextBox) on a worksheet without any **Selection** s or any references to the upper left-hand corner of the document, only the parameters of the range in question:

```
Sub CoverRange()
    Dim r As Range
    Dim L As Long, T As Long, W As Long, H As Long
    Set r = Range("A2:H8")
    L = r.Left
    T = r.Top
    W = r.Width
    H = r.Height
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes
        .AddTextbox(msoTextOrientationHorizontal, L, T, W, H).TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Test Box"
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

I marked @Gary's Student's answer as the best... but since I had trouble finding much info that related to what I was doing, I thought some code pasting here might help someone in the future.

The procedure @Gary's suggested can be adapted to cover a range of cells. I wanted to place a small shape on the right hand side of some cells in a range, that performed some functions on those cells. So, applying the `.AddShape` method:

```
Dim cl As Range, rg As Range
Set rg = Range("J2", Range("J2").End(xlDown))
For Each cl In rg
  With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(92, cl.Width - 10 + cl.Left, cl.Top + 5, 10, 10)
    .OnAction = "click_pm_update"
    .Name = cl.Row
    .Shadow.Visible = False
  End With
Next
```

This creates a small star to the right of each cell. The star's name reflects the row of that star, and when clicked it calls the "click_pm_update" procedure.

As a further note, click_pm_update uses the `Application.Caller` method, combined with the shape's name (which reflects the row the shape is in), to determine what cells to act on:

```
Private Sub click_pm_update()
Dim pmRow As String: pmRow = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).Name
'etc, etc
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267597/more-information-about-application-caller-with-vba-in-excel/11267846#11267846) for some useful info on the `Application.Caller` method.

The beauty of this is that the spreadsheet can continue to be used as normal until the user clicks on the shape. This adds a lot of customization to the spreadsheet.