# Detect indirect changes of multiple cells in Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet that has plenty of data validation lists that are directly dependent on each other.
So for example:

When I select a value from drop list in cell A2, it changes the list in cell A3 and thus changes the selected value on A3. This example is repeated over and over for different lists.

I am searching for a way to detect all the changes in those cells and write them (or their name in another column but same row) in another cell, just to tell the user what actually changed in the sheet. (we can also just change the color of the cells to reflect the change if that is easier)

The **Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)** doesn't seem to detect except the first change that happened in A2.

The question is quite generic but I can give an example if need.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have in **Worksheet_Change** event

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` is not triggered when a _formula_ changes a cells value.  But, since the chain of changes is triggered by a user change in one cell, you could use the `Precedents` property of the cell that does trigger the event to reference cells that depend on it.

Comment: @Zac I dont have a code yet. I am just building. I started with the following to see if I can detect the changes, then the code should be easy to read the changed cells and write them somewhere else:

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In Target
            Debug.Print cell.Address
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Maybe you could do it with `Worksheet_Calculate` but not tested

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks, I tried the precedents, it showed an error that there is no formula there. I tried also the Dependents (graphically) and it showed the right dependencies of that cell on data lists that I have in another sheet (called data).

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns `Worksheet_Calculate` doesn't have the target as argument and I didn't find a way to return what actually changed..

Comment: @afares so, if you found a property that gives you the References you need, is that not the answer to your question?

Comment: You could use `ActiveCell` to detect the active cell in the momento `Calculate` is triggered. Or maybe [Application.Caller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267597/more-information-about-application-caller-with-vba-in-excel)

Comment: @chrisneilsen not really but this could help. let me try to give an example. in A2 i have a list called list2 which is defined in sheet **data** and the selected value in A2 is called  val2. The list in A3 is called list3 and the selected value is called val3.
In **data** sheet I define the values of list3 as "i+val2 +1".
Using `Dependents` (graphically), i can see that A2 has dependency with list3 (in data sheet). But I cant detect A3.
Maybe I have to do another thing to detect it.
Another question, i tried to loop through Target.Dependents and print their address but the vba didnt work.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, can I detect all the cells that changed using your method. What is active cell ? I have say 5 cells that change at the same time when the selected cell changed. My problem is in detecting the other cells not the selected one..